# How to get Latitude/Longitude of user

Tags: iphone

How to get Latitude/Longitude of user when he makes or receives a call on iPhone. I want to save the location of my app's user whenever he makes or receives a call. Any how can I interact with the API of iPhone for this task. Any Suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't detect when a user receives a phone call for privacy reasons.

CoreLocation will give you the lag/long.